# Поиск мата psotgresql fts

Tags: postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Коллеги, помогите , пожалуйста , сделать поиск вхождение хотя бы одного слова из таблицы, в заданной строке, используя FTS. 
Нужно для реализации поиска мата.
1) Есть таблица с словами (матерными)
2) Есть текст который набрал пользователь
3) Формируем из текста пользователя to_tsvector
А дальше что?

```
    -- Table: mat

-- DROP TABLE mat;

CREATE TABLE mat
(
  word text
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE mat
  OWNER TO postgres;
```